# Navigation Drawer list view with 2 type

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer, listviewitem

I have a Navigation Drawer, With a ListView and with a header. When I scorll the drawer up down the items are mixed, the type of the items. Why?

My DrawerAdapter.java:

public class DrawerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context context;
private List<DrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
DrawerItemClickListener drawerItemClickListener;


public DrawerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DrawerItem> navDrawerItems,DrawerItemClickListener drawerItemClickListener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
    this.drawerItemClickListener = drawerItemClickListener;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return navDrawerItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return navDrawerItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}


static class ViewHolder {
ImageView imvIcon;
TextView textView;
LinearLayout layout;
}


@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    final DrawerItem mItem = navDrawerItems.get(position);

    if(mItem.getType().equals(DrawerItem.TYPE_CLICKABLE))
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);
            holder.imvIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
            holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
            holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_one_layout);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if(holder.imvIcon != null)
            Picasso.with(parent.getContext()).load(mItem.getIcon()).into(holder.imvIcon);
        if(holder.textView != null)
            holder.textView.setText(mItem.getTitle());

        if(holder.layout != null)
            holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    drawerItemClickListener.DrawerItemClicked(mItem);
                }
            });

    }
    else
    {

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item_two, parent, false);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_text);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

            holder.textView.setText(mItem.getTitle());

    }

    return convertView;
}}
```

And the Drawer Item :

public class DrawerItem {

```
public final static String TYPE_CLICKABLE = "clikc";

public final static String TYPE_HEADER = "header";

private String title, type;
private int icon;

public DrawerItem(String title, int icon, String type) {
    this.title = title;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.type = type;

}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public int getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public String getType() {return this.type;}}
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are not clearly stating which item type your current view is, so the adapter doesn't know the viewtype and doesn't display correctly the items (e.g. it mixes them).

In your `getItemViewType()` you should be clear about the viewtype of the current item, and do something like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getType().equals(DrawerItem.TYPE_CLICKABLE))
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```